# How to change db for whole block of code

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to change database for whole block of code. For example:

```
with using_db('my_other_db_conf'):
    MyModel.objects.all()
```

which would be equivalent of:

```
MyModel.objects.using('my_other_db_conf').all()
```

I just need to use different DB depending on context and don't like the idea of using *using()* method every time :\

Answer (score 0):

I'd use managers. In your models.py:

```
class DB_one_ItemsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(DB_one_ItemsManager, self).get_query_set().using("database1")

class DB_two_ItemsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(DB_two_ItemsManager, self).get_query_set().using("database2")

class YourModel(models.Model):    
    #Some fields here
    #...

    objects_db_one=DB_one_ItemsManager()
    objects_db_two=DB_two_ItemsManager()
```

Or if you want to use objects_db_one or objects_db_two as default manager simply rename it to objects

Comment: Yes. I thought about it but I need to use all my models so I'd need to define managers for all of them

Comment: @code22 The manager is model abstract - and therefore there will be ONLY one for each database, then you can insert the manager in each model you want.

Comment: but I can't add manager for User or any other model that I didn't define. I was looking for solution that would not require modifications to models.

Comment: @code22 set objects at runtime then. Try casting
My_model.objects = DB_one_ItemsManager() inside your code.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior needs to modify some global value, IMO, thus [`with statement`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) is not the apropriate way. Of course, it can be done, in a implicit, dirty and thread unsafe way:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager 
@contextmanager 
def unsafe_modify_queryset_db(model_dbs): 
    """model_dbs => sequence of tuple (model, db for the model to use).

    For example ((User, 'slice_2'), ...) 
    """ 
    prev_db = map(lambda x:x[0].objects._db , model_dbs) 
    for model, db in model_dbs: 
        model.objects._db = db 
    yield 
    # restore previous db 
    for x, db in zip(model_dbs, prev_db): 
        x[0].objects._db = prev_db 

# then
with unsafe_modify_queryset_db((User, 'slice_2', ...)):
    User.objects.filter(...)
```

You could also use [db_manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/multi-db/#using-managers-with-multiple-databases) to operate on QuerySet level, which achieves the same goal as luke14free's code:

```
qs = User.objects.db_manager('slice_2')
foo = qs.filter(...)
bar = qs.filter(...)
```

Remember that *Explicit is better than implicit*, just arrange your code and enclose querysets sharing same db to function call, would be better.

Comment: the thread safety is the main reason that rules out global variable that would solve the case. I'll have to use at least few db operations on different models in a block of code so such a with statement would make code much more readable and straightforward but maybe that's wrong thinking. Anyway I guess I'll have to use _using()_. thx

Comment: @code22 yes, better to put `using()` to top level to reduce redundant, just as I mentioned in `db_manager` part in the answer.